# If master node failed then how can recover all data on master node and how to again start hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari, bigdata

I have three master,slave1,salve2 cluser server of hadoop and My question is like if master server of ambari system failed then how can we recover ? Do we need to add new server and install ambari again or how can we recover our data from failed server. if added new server we can assign as master then how can we do ? could suggest me about master server down then how can resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Hadoop 2, you can run a Standby namenode to achieve High Availability. Without that, your cluster's master will be a Single Point of Failure. You can not retrieve the data of Namenode from anywhere else since it is different from the usual data you store. If your namenode goes down, your blocks and files will still be there, but you won't be able to access them since there would be no related metadata in the namenode.

Answer (score 0):

No data retrieval of data if the Name Node dies and you have no backup. You need a backup Name Node (aka Secondary Name Node)  which will take metadata backup after every fixed interval. This interval is generally long so u still lose some data

With hadoop 2.0 u can take more frequent backup with help of a passive name node which becomes active if the main name node dies and data is still accessible.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You means if my master server crash due to electricity failure or something else if not started  so how can get namenode data ? Can I retrive from other cluster node server like slave1 or slave 2 server ? Please suggest me for backup recovery of hadoop echo system.

Comment: That is what i explained u need another node(Secondary or Passive) which will have backup metadata so u can restore your main Name Node. In any case you will need to install a secondary node.

Comment: secondary namenode can not remove the problem of SPOF. That is done by Standby namenode.

Comment: @philantrovert i know he was asking of ways to get data that is why i mentioned passive name node as well thanks for pointing out SPOF though